# datatables keep existing fnServerParams on fnReloadAjax

Tags: jquery

I am trying to modify fnReloadAjax to keep existing aoData i have set before in

```
  fnServerParams:function(aoData) {
     var serializedForm = $('form#searchform').serializeArray();
     for (var n in serializedForm) {
        var tmpobj = serializedForm[n];
        var key = tmpobj['name'];
        var value = tmpobj['value'];
        aoData.push({"name":key,"value":value});
     }
}
```

and they are reset in

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnReloadAjax = function ( oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback,bStandingRedraw )
...
...
...
var aData = []; # reset here
```

how can I get existing aData params instead of reseting them to empty array?

Answer (score 0):

fnReloadAjax() doesn't work with bServerSide = true